# How to detect SMTP AUTH attempts in Fail2Ban?

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, fail2ban

I have a Fail2Ban jail that monitors failed SASL authentications to my Postfix SMTP server. When this occurs, `/var/log/mail.log` contains these three lines:

```
postfix/smtpd[32591]: connect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
postfix/smtpd[32591]: warning: unknown[x.x.x.x]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
postfix/smtpd[32591]: disconnect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
```

And Fail2Ban filters the warning line: if it is found, the IP is considered for banning.

Recently, I changed Postfix so that AUTH is available over TLS only (using option `smtpd_tls_auth_only`). A consequence is that the warning line is not generated anymore when someone tries to authenticate without TLS:

```
postfix/smtpd[22469]: connect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
postfix/smtpd[22469]: disconnect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
```

Which means Fail2Ban is not able to monitor all SASL authentication attempts anymore. How can I do that?

A solution I came up with is to make SMTP more verbose (appending `-v` to `smtpd` in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`) and parse appropriate lines, but my problem with this is that the `-v` option makes the logs too verbose:

```
postfix/smtpd[23185]: connect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_list_match: x.x.x.x: no match
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_list_match: x.x.x.x: no match
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_hostaddr: x.x.x.x ~? 127.0.0.0/8
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_hostaddr: x.x.x.x ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_hostaddr: x.x.x.x ~? [::1]/128
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_list_match: x.x.x.x: no match
postfix/smtpd[23185]: send attr ident = smtp:x.x.x.x
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 220 example.org ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
postfix/smtpd[23185]: < unknown[x.x.x.x]: EHLO User
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_list_match: x.x.x.x: no match
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-example.org
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-PIPELINING
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-SIZE 10240000
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-VRFY
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-ETRN
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-STARTTLS
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250-8BITMIME
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250 DSN
postfix/smtpd[23185]: < unknown[x.x.x.x]: RSET
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 250 2.0.0 Ok
postfix/smtpd[23185]: < unknown[x.x.x.x]: AUTH LOGIN
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
postfix/smtpd[23185]: < unknown[x.x.x.x]: QUIT
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 221 2.0.0 Bye
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_hostaddr: x.x.x.x ~? 127.0.0.0/8
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_hostaddr: x.x.x.x ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_hostaddr: x.x.x.x ~? [::1]/128
postfix/smtpd[23185]: match_list_match: x.x.x.x: no match
postfix/smtpd[23185]: send attr ident = smtp:x.x.x.x
postfix/smtpd[23185]: disconnect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
```

A priori, I only need to filter the `authentication not enabled` line. Is it possible to make the SMTP service to report auth requests without adding the whole verbose messages? Ideally my `mail.log` file would only contain:

```
postfix/smtpd[32591]: connect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
postfix/smtpd[32591]: warning: unknown[x.x.x.x]: authentication not enabled
postfix/smtpd[32591]: disconnect from unknown[x.x.x.x]
```

Is this something possible? If yes, how? Thanks,

Comment: If the clients are using `EHLO` they should be aware that AUTH isn't available without TLS.  They may no longer be trying.   I would expect a different messages.  Try using `telnet` to see what your server is saying and what error it generates for an `AUTH` request without `TLS`.

Comment: @BillThor What do you mean by "They may no longer be trying"? I tried using Telnet, and I have a behavior similar to the output in the verbose log.

Comment: With auth disabled they shouldn't get anywhere near a SASL login without TLS.  The 503 is a server error indicating LOGIN is not enabled. They won't be able to attempt a login. You may want to filter on connect from unknown as this is an indicator that the connection most likely did not come from a legitimate email server.

Comment: Thanks @BillThor I did as you suggested (filtering on `connect from unknown`) and I can detect the AUTH attempt as I wanted. However, do you have an idea why even with an IP banned by iptables, Postfix reports AUTH attempt anyway? Thanks again.

Comment: This Question is a perfect explanation for my problem. Had a lot of "attackes" that know they could make an AUTH because of the EHLO answer, but make a AUTH request and after that they - clean QUIT. It would be perfect to have an solution to get any info into the logfile, to block them with a fail2ban rule.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of adding `-v` to `smtpd` helped me solve this problem. I'm on Debian.

First I created `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[postfix]
enabled = true
logpath = /var/log/mail.log
bantime = 86400
findtime = 86400
maxretry = 2
```

This tells `fail2ban` to watch `/var/log/mail.log` with a maximum of 2 attempts during 24 hours, which would lead to a ban of 24 hours as well.

Then I copied `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix.conf` to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix.local`, and added this line:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s> \S+\[<HOST>\]: 503 5\.5\.1 .*$
```

This would trigger upon:

```
postfix/smtpd[23185]: > unknown[x.x.x.x]: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled
```

**UPDATE** (October 2021):

Above works nicely with fail2ban 0.9.6. However, fail2ban 0.10.2 changed the layout of postfix.conf a bit.

To fix, again, copy the new `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix.conf` to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix.local`. In this `.local` file, edit the *normal* section as follows:

```
mdpr-normal = (?:NOQUEUE: reject:|improper command pipelining after \S+|>)
mdre-normal=^RCPT from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: 55[04] 5\.7\.1\s
            ^RCPT from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: 45[04] 4\.7\.1 (?:Service unavailable\b|Client host rejected: cannot find your (reverse )?hostname\b)
            ^RCPT from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: 450 4\.7\.1 (<[^>]*>)?: Helo command rejected: Host not found\b
            ^EHLO from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: 504 5\.5\.2 (<[^>]*>)?: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname\b
            ^VRFY from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: 550 5\.1\.1\s
            ^RCPT from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s: 450 4\.1\.8 (<[^>]*>)?: Sender address rejected: Domain not found\b
            ^from [^[]*\[<HOST>\]%(_port)s:?
            ^[^[]*\[<HOST>\]: 503 5\.5\.1 Error: authentication not enabled\b
```

Note the addition of `|>` to `mdpr-normal`.

In `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, add `mode = normal` to the `[postfix]` section.

And do not forget to add `-v` to the `smtp` directive in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd -v
```

Restart your services and you should be good to go.